# Get the intersection and difference between two huge files

Tags: linux, shell, grep, uniq

I have two huge files, each has more than 400, 000, 000 lines, with a size of more than 13GB, each line contains a md5 number(32 bytes). I want to get the intersection  between the two files, also I want to get the difference of them. I wonder if there is a simple yet fast way to do this, like using linux shell command.

Comment: Please clarify a little bit: 1) Can one md5 numbers appears for many times in a same file? 2) Are those md5 numbers sorted?  3) Define what you mean by intersection? For example, if both file contains all identical numbers but just in different orders, are they considered the same, in your definition of intersection/diff?  i.e. you are trying to find which numbers appear in both files, and which number appear in just one of the files (and also output which file)?

Comment: perhaps just a `diff <(sort file1)  <(sort file2)` will do the job?

Comment: thank you for your comment, 1) each md5 number appears only once in a file 2) the numbers are sorted 3) intersection means common number, not considering the order

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the files are sorted, then `comm` will do the job:

Intersection (lines in both files):

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

Difference (lines in one file but not the other):

```
comm -3 file1 file2
```

Note that in the second case, the lines only in `file2` will be indented by a tab; if you want to remove that, filter the output through `sed`.

If the files are not already sorted, you can do it on the fly with [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
comm -3  <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

You can also run the command once; the lines starting with 0 tabs are only in `file1`; those starting with 1 tab are only in `file2`; those starting with 2 tabs are in both files.